# CakePHP 2.2.3 authentication error

Tags: cakephp, authentication

When I try to authenticate it says `Your username or password was incorrect.` even if I just created the user. When I try `debug($this->Auth->login())` I get the message `false`. What is wrong with my code?

The model - UserModel.php:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 * @property WashMachine $WashMachine
 */
class User extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */ 
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }

    public function bindNode($user) {
        return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
    }

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'group_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'WashMachine' => array(
            'className' => 'WashMachine',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

The AppController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Application level Controller
 *
 * This file is application-wide controller file. You can put all
 * application-wide controller-related methods here.
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {

        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->authorize = array(
            'Controller',
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        );
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'login', 'password' => 'password')));
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false);

    }
    function isAuthorized($user) {
        // return false;
        return $this->Auth->loggedIn();
    }

}
```

The UserController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property User $User
 */
class UsersController extends AppController {
    function beforeFilter(){
       parent::beforeFilter();
       $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
            }
        }
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
            $this->redirect('/', null, false);
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
 /**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('groups'));
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
        $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('groups'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws MethodNotAllowedException
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

The Login.cp view:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you remapping "username" to login" in your Form settings
but your login form still contains "username" as field name?

drop the remapping OR change the field in your form to "User.login"
since you seem to have a database field username the first should be done:

```
'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change
from:-

```
 $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'login', 'password' => 'password')));
```

to:-

```
 $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')));
```

or you can drop this line completely as it will take the default AuthComponent values defined